# ffmpeg video compression / specific file size

Tags: ffmpeg

Currently I have 80mb movies that I want to use ffmpeg to convert down to say about 10mb or 15mb.  I know there will be a quality loss but they will need to have sound.  Is there a way to either specify a file size or higher compression than what I have done previously

```
ffmpeg -i movie.mp4 -b 2255k -s 1280x720 movie.hd.ogv
```

They are currently about 25mb a piece

Answer (score 47):

if you are targeting a certain output file size the best way is to use **H.264** and **Two-Pass encoding**.

There is a great example here but it's too large to copy-paste:
https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264#twopass

You calculate your target bitrate using `bitrate = target size / duration` and you launch **ffmpeg** two times: one pass analyzes the media and the second does the actual encoding:

```
ffmpeg -y -i input -c:v libx264 -preset medium -b:v 555k -pass 1 -c:a libfdk_aac -b:a 128k -f mp4 /dev/null && \
ffmpeg -i input -c:v libx264 -preset medium -b:v 555k -pass 2 -c:a libfdk_aac -b:a 128k output.mp4
```

Edit: H.265 (HEVC) is even better at compression (50% of H.264 size in some cases) but support is not yet widespread so stick with H.264 for now.

Comment: In your calculation, what are the units on file size and duration?

Comment: @DrewChapin kilo bits / second

Comment: Also H.265 can be detrimental on slow PCs or mobile devices because it's considerably more CPU intensive.

Comment: How do we do this in Windows Command Terminal aka MSDOS, since it uses a weird two-line syntax?

Comment: @rac SEE https://stackoverflow.com/a/69304825/8826818

Comment: Thanks @aergistal I tried to this method it's really cool actually but not working on my example. Can you check it? https://stackoverflow.com/q/69403015/13772090

Comment: @raccoon use ```NUL && ^``` instead of ```dev null && \```. Or ```filenamehere && ^``` which will create an intermediary file.

Comment: Simple script of this answer provided below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78054257

Answer (score 42):

Inspired by Hashbrown's answer. This version keeps the original audio quality, and resizes to the target size.

**NEW**

1. Renamed variables for readability and consistency.
2. Removed dependency on `grep` (`-P` switch not implemented in OSX grep)
3. The script now exits with a helpful message if the target size would be too small.

#### Script

```bash
#!/bin/bash
#
# Re-encode a video to a target size in MB.
# Example:
#    ./this_script.sh video.mp4 15

T_SIZE="$2" # target size in MB
T_FILE="${1%.*}-$2MB.mp4" # filename out

# Original duration in seconds
O_DUR=$(\
    ffprobe \
    -v error \
    -show_entries format=duration \
    -of csv=p=0 "$1")

# Original audio rate
O_ARATE=$(\
    ffprobe \
    -v error \
    -select_streams a:0 \
    -show_entries stream=bit_rate \
    -of csv=p=0 "$1")

# Original audio rate in KiB/s
O_ARATE=$(\
    awk \
    -v arate="$O_ARATE" \
    'BEGIN { printf "%.0f", (arate / 1024) }')

# Target size is required to be less than the size of the original audio stream
T_MINSIZE=$(\
    awk \
    -v arate="$O_ARATE" \
    -v duration="$O_DUR" \
    'BEGIN { printf "%.2f", ( (arate * duration) / 8192 ) }')

# Equals 1 if target size is ok, 0 otherwise
IS_MINSIZE=$(\
    awk \
    -v size="$T_SIZE" \
    -v minsize="$T_MINSIZE" \
    'BEGIN { print (minsize < size) }')

# Give useful information if size is too small
if [[ $IS_MINSIZE -eq 0 ]]; then
    printf "%s\n" "Target size ${T_SIZE}MB is too small!" >&2
    printf "%s %s\n" "Try values larger than" "${T_MINSIZE}MB" >&2
    exit 1
fi

# Set target audio bitrate
T_ARATE=$O_ARATE


# Calculate target video rate - MB -> KiB/s
T_VRATE=$(\
    awk \
    -v size="$T_SIZE" \
    -v duration="$O_DUR" \
    -v audio_rate="$O_ARATE" \
    'BEGIN { print  ( ( size * 8192.0 ) / ( 1.048576 * duration ) - audio_rate) }')

# Perform the conversion
ffmpeg \
    -y \
    -i "$1" \
    -c:v libx264 \
    -b:v "$T_VRATE"k \
    -pass 1 \
    -an \
    -f mp4 \
    /dev/null \
&& \
ffmpeg \
    -i "$1" \
    -c:v libx264 \
    -b:v "$T_VRATE"k \
    -pass 2 \
    -c:a aac \
    -b:a "$T_ARATE"k \
    "$T_FILE"
```

#### NOTES

- See comments for a possible Windows version.

#### SOURCES

[Hashbrown's answer (in this thread)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58122773/10059841)

[Two Pass method](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264#twopass)

**Windows version since link no longer works in the comment**

```
@echo off
REM Windows implementation of Marian Minar's answer to "ffmpeg video compression / specific file size" https://stackoverflow.com/a/61146975/2902367
SET "video=%~1"
SET "target_video_size_MB=%~2"
SET "output_file=%~dpn1 %~2MB.mp4"
REM I usually don't see a big difference between two-pass and single-pass... set to anything but "true" to turn off two-pass encoding
SET "twopass=true"
REM We need a way to do floating point arithmetic in CMD, here is a quick one. Change the path to a location that's convenient for you
set "mathPath=c:\bin\Math.vbs"
REM Creating the Math VBS file
if not exist "%mathPath%" echo Wscript.echo replace(eval(WScript.Arguments(0)),",",".")>%mathPath%

echo Converting to %target_video_size_MB% MB: "%video%"
echo -^> "%output_file%"
pause
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
REM Getting the (audio) duration. TODO: watch out for differing audio/video durations?
FOR /F "delims=" %%i IN ('ffprobe -v error -show_streams -select_streams a "%~1"') DO (
    SET "line=%%i"
    if "!line:~0,9!" == "duration=" (
        SET "duration=!line:~9!"
    )
)
REM Getting the audio bitrate
FOR /F "delims=" %%i IN ('ffprobe -v error -pretty -show_streams -select_streams a "%~1"') DO (
    SET "line=%%i"
    SET /A "c=0"
    if "!line:~0,9!" == "bit_rate=" (
        FOR %%a IN (!line:~9!) DO (
            if "!c!" == "0" (
                SET "audio_rate=%%a"
            )
            SET /A "c+=1"
        )
    )
)
REM TODO: Adjust target audio bitrate. Use source bitrate for now.
SET "target_audio_bitrate=%audio_rate%"

call:Math %target_video_size_MB% * 8192 / (1.048576 * %duration%) - %target_audio_bitrate%
SET "target_video_bitrate=%result%"

echo %target_audio_bitrate% audio, %target_video_bitrate% video

SET "passString="
if "%twopass%" == "true" (
    echo Two-Pass Encoding
    ffmpeg ^
        -y ^
        -i "%~1" ^
        -c:v libx264 ^
        -b:v %target_video_bitrate%k ^
        -pass 1 ^
        -an ^
        -f mp4 ^
        nul
    SET "passString=-pass 2"
) else ( echo Single-Pass Encoding )
ffmpeg ^
    -i "%~1" ^
    -c:v libx264 ^
    -b:v %target_video_bitrate%k ^
    %passString% ^
    -c:a aac ^
    -b:a %target_audio_bitrate%k ^
    "%output_file%"
    
pause
GOTO :EOF

:Math
REM echo Working : "%*"
for /f %%a in ('cscript /nologo %mathPath% "%*"') do set "Result=%%a"
GOTO :EOF
```

Comment: `$1` should be quoted on lines 4 and 5 in case the file path contains spaces. On a related note, "Edits must be at least 6 characters" is a dumb rule for a programming site.

Comment: `$1`s now quoted thanks 9072997. Or is it 907 for short?

Comment: If your input contains multiple audio streams you may need to change `-select_streams a` to `-select_streams a:0` on both of the ffprobe lines.

Comment: it shouldnt need to be an integer, I didn't run yours, but my original takes "7.5" so I think yours might/could. This is handy since the algorithm seems to overshoot (8 generates an 8.5mB file, which discord wont like, but 7.8 is pretty dead on without dropping down to 7-flat)

Comment: Where does `1.048576` come from?

Comment: @FlorianCargoet good question. kiB - kB conversion. However, now that I look back at this answer, I'm not sure I know why I thought I needed to do this.

Comment: @MarianMinar wouldn't it be 1024 / 1000 = 1.024 ?

Comment: @FlorianCargoet sorry I meant miB - mB.

Comment: Very nice. Not as straight forward to convert to usage for Windows CMD as you made it sound; here is my implementation with credits to you and this answer: https://gist.github.com/svArtist/e1b0c8526abaffc9f6ffc63d232b53d5

Comment: @BenPhilipp haha, yes, you're very right - thanks for the CMD version. I added a note in my answer - it's tempting to get rid of that part altogether.

Comment: Eliminate `grep` with `origin_duration_s=$(ffprobe -v error -show_entries format=duration -of csv=p=0 "$1")`. Note that `origin_audio_bitrate_kbit_s` won't work for all formats, notable Matroska (mkv) inputs. But you can also remove `grep` from that too: `origin_audio_bitrate_kbit_s=$(ffprobe -v error -select_streams a:0 -show_entries stream=bit_rate -of csv=p=0 "$1")`

Comment: @llogan This is great, also because grep's `-P` option doesn't seem to be supported on MacOS by default (see [stackoverflow.com/a/45534127/7669319](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45534127/7669319))

Comment: I'm not an awk wizard; how would you modify this script to include an optional resize step in a single operation? Also note that the current script will reincode the audio to its original bitrate, which is overkill in the (common) case the audio is AAC-encoded already.

Answer (score 11):

Here's a way to do it automatically with a bash script
Just call like `./script.sh file.mp4 15` for `15mB`

```bash
bitrate="$(awk "BEGIN {print int($2 * 1024 * 1024 * 8 / $(ffprobe \
    -v error \
    -show_entries format=duration \
    -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 \
    "$1" \
) / 1000)}")k"
ffmpeg \
    -y \
    -i "$1" \
    -c:v libx264 \
    -preset medium \
    -b:v $bitrate \
    -pass 1 \
    -an \
    -f mp4 \
    /dev/null \
&& \
ffmpeg \
    -i "$1" \
    -c:v libx264 \
    -preset medium \
    -b:v $bitrate \
    -pass 2 \
    -an \
    "${1%.*}-$2mB.mp4"
```

NB I'm cutting audio out

Comment: How to not cut audio?

Comment: OK. Solution is to remove lines with `-an`

Comment: Mm, I just didn't try because it will no longer match the size you want to make. To include audio AND have a filesize-ceiling you need to decide a bitrate ratio and so reduce audio qualtiy, not just `-b:v`, and also make sure these two add up right.

Comment: If you want to preserve the audio "as is" (which I usually want), then you can of course use something like ffprobe to determine the size of the audio track. Subtract that size from the target size to obtain the remaining size that can be used for video track. I find you need to subtract 2Mb from that for the MP4 container. A recent example, downsizing a 200Mb, 720p video to a 640x360 version aiming for 64Mb (got 63.9Mb): `ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -filter:v scale=640:-1 -c:a copy -b:v 630k out.mp4`; the `-c:a copy` gives me the original audio in the output video.

Comment: AWK? Seriously? `$(( $2 * 1024 * 1024 * 8 / $( ... ) ))`. This is not even bash, this is POSIX shell and will work even in dash, ash, etc.

Comment: @Mecki did you even try your code? Don't come in here acting all high and mighty when you don't even know that a decimal (eg `$2 = 7.5`) will break your precious POSIX as a syntax error

Comment: @Hashbrown Even then you'd use `printf` to cut of the decimal (`printf '%.0f' $( ffprobe ...`) or use `bc` if you want float calculations. Using a pattern matching language to perform a simple math calculation is ridiculous.

Answer (score 3):

Reduce video to pre-determined file size using Windows 10, cmd and ffmpeg.

Use H.264 and Two-Pass encoding.

Calculate your bitrate using `bitrate = target file size / duration`

Target file size in kilobits. Duration in seconds. 1 MB = 8192kb

Split the bitrate between video and audio, about 3/4 video, 1/4 audio. The sum of the audio and video bitrate must not exceed the calculated bitrate.

`-c:a libfdk_aac` does not work for me.

```
ffmpeg -y -i input -c:v libx264 -b:v CALCULATED BITRATE HERE -pass 1 -an -f null nul && ^ffmpeg -y -i input -c:v libx264 -b:v CALCULATED BITRATE HERE -pass 2 -c:a aac -b:a CALCULATED BITRATE HERE output.mp4

ffmpeg -y -i 1.mp4 -c:v libx264 -b:v 555k -pass 1 -an -f null nul && ^ffmpeg -y -i 1.mp4 -c:v libx264 -b:v 555k -pass 2 -c:a aac -b:a 128k output.mp4
```

See https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264#twopass

Comment: Why does it look like you have 4 ffmpeg calls here?

Answer (score 0):

A great way to slash video size *to a fraction* if prioritizing audio, by reducing resolution.

-filter:v "scale=-1:ih*1/2:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease" -max_muxing_queue_size 1024

Comment: Reducing frames per second doesn't really work because of the way video is compressed, only the differences from frame to frame are encoded. If you reduce the frame rate a lot, then every frame basically becomes a big key frame. You don't end up saving that much. But reducing resolution is very effective.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a simplified version of the answer from @aergistal so that you can just plug your input values and call it a day:

```bash
##
# Input Values
##

source_file_path='/Users/me/Downloads/video.mp4'
output_file_path='/Users/me/Downloads/video.mkv'

target_video_megabytes=8
target_audio_megabytes=1


##
# Bitrate Calculations
##

source_duration_seconds=$(ffprobe -v error -show_entries format=duration -of csv=p=0 "$source_file_path")

target_video_bitrate=$(( $target_video_megabytes * 8388.608 / $source_duration_seconds ))
target_video_bitrate="${target_video_bitrate%.*}k"

target_audio_bitrate=$(( $target_audio_megabytes * 8388.608 / $source_duration_seconds ))
target_audio_bitrate="${target_audio_bitrate%.*}k"


##
# Encoding
##

ffmpeg -y -i "$source_file_path" -c:v libx264 -preset medium -b:v "$target_video_bitrate" -pass 1 -c:a aac -b:a "$target_audio_bitrate" -f mp4 /dev/null && \
ffmpeg -i "$source_file_path" -c:v libx264 -preset medium -b:v "$target_video_bitrate" -pass 2 -c:a aac -b:a "$target_audio_bitrate" "$output_file_path"
```

Answer (score -4):

Just decreasing the frame rate - if you do not need to have a high frame rate, like in a tutorial - you will decrease the size of the video file significantly, and with this filter you want lose the audio sync

ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter:v fps=fps=10 output.mp4