# FFMPEG getting exact desired file size

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a 2 seconds length 1920x1080 dimensions video and I want to size of the file to be 3Mb

I tried the method below:

```
const fileSize = 3000; // Kilobytes
const duration = 2; // Second
const videoBitRate = Math.round((fileSize * 8) / duration));
```

So videoBitRate is 12000 right now

Then I use `Two-Pass encoding`

```
ffmpeg -y -i input -c:v libx264 -preset medium -b:v 12000k -pass 1 -c:a aac -b:a 128k -f mp4 /dev/null && \
ffmpeg -i input -c:v libx264 -preset medium -b:v 12000k -pass 2 -c:a aac -b:a 128k output.mp4
```

Expecting file size: 3Mb

Actual file size: 2.6Mb

---

If I'd use a 35 seconds video,

`videoBitRate = 685k`

```
ffmpeg -y -i input -c:v libx264 -preset medium -b:v 685k -pass 1 -c:a aac -b:a 128k -f mp4 /dev/null && \
ffmpeg -i input -c:v libx264 -preset medium -b:v 685k -pass 2 -c:a aac -b:a 128k output.mp4
```

Expecting file size: 3Mb

Actual file size: 3.6Mb

What is the point I'm doing wrong?

Isn't there a more accurate way to calculate? Why are the results always different?

Comment: You also have one or more audio tracks at 128 kbps which you have to factor in along with a bit of format overhead.

Comment: Hmm, how can I add this to the equation?

Comment: Calculate the size of the audio tracks (`audio_bitrate * duration * nb_audio_tracks`) and subtract it from the target file size along with let's say 1% of the file size for MP4 overhead to be safe, then use the reminder to determine the video bitrate. If you have subtitles or other tracks make sure to leave space for them too.

Comment: Perfect, thanks @aergistal ! I'll improve my formulation and write it to this question as an answer