# bash grep - negative match

Tags: regex, bash, regex-negation

I want to show flag places in my Python unittests where I have been lazy and de-activated tests.

But I also have conditional executions that are not laziness, they are motivated by performance or system conditions at time of testing.  Those are the **skipUnless** ones and I want to ignore them entirely.

Let's take some inputs that I have put in a file, **test_so_bashregex.txt**, with some comments.

```
!ignore this, because skipUnless means I have an acceptable conditional flag
@unittest.skipUnless(do_test, do_test_msg)
def test_conditional_function():
    xxx

!catch these 2, lazy test-passing
@unittest.skip("fb212.test_urls_security_usergroup Test_Detail.test_related fails with 302")
def sometest_function():
    xxx
@unittest.expectedFailure
def test_another_function():
    xxx

!bonus points... ignore things that are commented out
   # @unittest.expectedFailure
```

Additionally, I can't use a `grep -v skipUnless` in a pipe because I really want to use `egrep -A 3 xxx *.py` to give some context, as in:

`grep -A 3 "@unittest\." *.py`

```
test_backend_security_meta.py:    @unittest.skip("rewrite - data can be legitimately missing")
test_backend_security_meta.py-    def test_storage(self):
test_backend_security_meta.py-        with getMultiDb() as mdb:
test_backend_security_meta.py-
```

**What I have tried:**

Trying @ https://www.debuggex.com/

I tried `@unittest\.(.+)(?!(Unless\())`  and that didn't work, as it matches the first 3.

Ditto `@unittest\.[a-zA-Z]+(?!(Unless\())`

`@unittest\.skip(?!(Unless\())` worked partially, on the 2 with skip.

All of those do partial matches despite the presence of *Unless*.

on bash egrep, which is where this going to end up, things don't look much better.

`jluc@explore$ egrep  '@unittest\..*(?!(Unless))' test_so_bashregex.txt`
egrep: repetition-operator operand invalid

Answer (score 1):

you could [try this regex](https://regex101.com/r/rH4jQ2/2):

```
(?<!#\s)@unittest\.(?!skipUnless)(skip|expectedFailure).*
```

if you don't care if 'skip' or 'expectedFailure' appear you could simplify it:

```
(?<!#\s)@unittest\.(?!skipUnless).*
```

Comment: No, skip and expectedFailure don't really matter.  It's only the skipUnless I care about, in order to avoid it.   `@unittest\.(?!skipUnless).*` works well in the online test.  But on bash, I get the **repetition-operator operand invalid**.  I'll add that it's bash on OSX, because I know that grep/egrep differ slightly there, compared to Linux variants.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this - grep seems a bit restrictive

```
items=$(find . -name "*.py")
for item in $items; do
    cat $item | awk ' 
    /^\@unittest.*expectedFailure/{seen_skip=1;}
    /^\@unittest.*skip/{seen_skip=1;}
    /^def/{
        if (seen_skip == 1)
            print "Being lazy at " $1
        seen_skip=0;
    }
    '
done
```

Comment: Well, in real life, the lines are not sitting in a test.txt file, they are picked up by *grep xxx* **\*.py**.  so I'd wouldn't be getting the filenames and line #s unless I had an extra step piping that info to awk.  Your code does work, printing out *'Being lazy at def'* 3 times.

Comment: Updated to loop over all py's - should be able to extend that find however you have your test files structures

Comment: ok, and it does pick the \*.py's apparently, but the output is still just *Being lazy at def*.  So **$1** is only 'def', all of the time.  No *@unittest* directive, filename, line # or even the actual function code.  Appreciate the effort, that's why I upvoted you, but it looks shakier & more complicated so far than my solution.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I'll put up what I found with *sweaver2112*'s help, but if someone has a good single-stage grep-ready regex, I'll take it.

bash's egrep/grep doesn't like `?!` (ref [grep: repetition-operator operand invalid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15538452/grep-repetition-operator-operand-invalid)).  end of story there.

What I have done instead is to pipe it to some extra filters: negative grep -v skipUnless and another one to strip leading comments.  These 2 strip out the unwanted lines.  But, then pipe their output back into another grep looking for @unittest again and again with the -A 3 flag.

If the negative greps have cleared out a line, it won't show in the last pipestage so drops out of the input.  If not, I get my context right back.

```
egrep -A 3 -n '@unittest\.' test_so_bashregex.txt  | egrep -v "^\s*#" | egrep -v "skipUnless\(" | grep @unittest -A 3
```

output:

```
7:@unittest.skip("fb212.test_urls_security_usergroup Test_Detail.test_related fails with 302")
8-def sometest_function():
9-  xxx
10:@unittest.expectedFailure
11-def test_another_function():
12- xxx
```

And my actual output from running it on * *.py*, rather than my test.txt file:

```
 egrep -A 3 -n '@unittest\.' *.py  | egrep -v "\d:\s*#" | egrep -v "skipUnless\(" | grep @unittest -A 3
```

output:

```
test_backend_security_meta.py:77:    @unittest.skip("rewrite - data can be legitimately missing")
test_backend_security_meta.py-78-    def test_storage(self):
test_backend_security_meta.py-79-        with getMultiDb() as mdb:
test_backend_security_meta.py-80-
--
test_backend_security_meta.py:98:    @unittest.skip("rewrite - data can be legitimately missing")
test_backend_security_meta.py-99-    def test_get_li_tag_for_object(self):
test_backend_security_meta.py-100-        li = self.mgr.get_li_tag()
test_backend_security_meta.py-101-
```